# Using QgsGeometryAnalyzer.dissolve

Tags: pyqgis, dissolve

I am completely new to the QGIS python api and I am running into an error which I cannot solve when trying to use the dissolve class.

I used the basics of the PyQGIS Cookbook. In my  understanding the problem lies within the "layer". But as I understand it, that is exactly whats assigned to that variable.
Probably it is just a simple error I am running in, as I am not experienced using python.

In essence I just need a script which performs a dissolve on a shapefile with the option "dissolve all" like it is implemented within QGIS.

Code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.analysis import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

data_source = "test.shp"
layer_name = "test"
provider_name = "ogr"

layer = QgsVectorLayer(data_source, layer_name, provider_name)
if not layer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"

QgsGeometryAnalyzer.dissolve(layer, "test_dissolved.shp", onlySelectedFeatures=False, uniqueIdField=-1, p=None)
```

Error:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/testproject/dissolve.py", line 17, in <module>
QgsGeometryAnalyzer.dissolve(layer, "dissolved.shp", onlySelectedFeatures=False, uniqueIdField=-1, p=None)
TypeError: QgsGeometryAnalyzer.dissolve(QgsVectorLayer, QString, bool onlySelectedFeatures=False, int uniqueIdField=-1, QProgressDialog p=None): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsGeometryAnalyzer'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the syntax error:

```
QgsGeometryAnalyzer().dissolve(layer, "test_dissolved.shp", onlySelectedFeatures=False,     uniqueIdField=-1, p=None)
```

That does the trick.